# libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config error with Python 3.4.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu-12.04

I just managed to install Python v3.4.5 under Ubuntu 12.04. While trying the following codes from openCV-python library

```
 import cv2

 img = cv2.imread('img.png',0)
 cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

I am recieving this error:

```
 /usr/local/bin/python3.4 /home/yas/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.py
 OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 545
 Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have tried a few solution recommended on the web but the problem still remains unsolved. How can I overcome this issue in your view?

Comment: it seems that you have problem with GUI. Possibly installing libgtk2.0-dev and rebuilding OpenCV can help

Answer (score 0):

First you should try this

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-*
```

Then **reboot** your system and based on your package manager run the following command

- conda:

  $ conda remove opencv

  $ conda install -c conda-forge opencv
- pip

  $ pip install opencv-contrib-python